# Using only one API if another one does not have data

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous

```
const getUser = async (user) => {
    const body = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.com/api/public/users?name=' + user);
    const userInfo = JSON.parse(body.text);
    const r = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.com/api/public/users/' + userInfo.uniqueId + '/profile');
    const extraUserInfo = JSON.parse(r.text);
    const _message = await client.users.get('437502925019807744').send({ files: ['https://www.website.nl/avatar-imaging/avatarimage?figure=h' + userInfo.figureString + '.png'] });
    const avatarImage = _message.attachments.first().url;
    return { userInfo, extraUserInfo, avatarImage };
};

getUser(args[0]).then((result) => {
    message.channel.send(`${result.userInfo.name}`);
}).catch(function(result) {
    console.log(result.userInfo.name);
});
```

Here I am trying to use 3 API's, however it always goes to the catch, even if one exists and other don't, I tried to only use `result.userInfo.name` to only use the first API, also in the catch I use the first one, then I tried a name that only has the first API but not the second one however I still get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` because it looks at the second API as well, what else can I do to handle with this situation? So basically how can I only catch errors for the first API

edit: I also tried:

```
    if (extraUserInfo.user.name) {return { userInfo, extraUserInfo, avatarImage };}
    else {return { userInfo, avatarImage };}
```

Comment: Do the three APIs, when working properly, return the same thing in their `userinfo.name` property?

Comment: But for some names only the first one works so I only want to catch errors for the first one, if the first one exists and the second one doesn't, I can just use fallback values for the values that are missing in the second API

Comment: Conditional code without conditions?

Comment: I have updated the question with something else I tried, to hopefully make more clear what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with a try catch

```
try {
    const r = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.com/api/public/users/' + userInfo.uniqueId + '/profile');
    const extraUserInfo = JSON.parse(r.text);
    return {
        userInfo,
        extraUserInfo,
        avatarImage
    };
} catch (error) {
    const extraUserInfo = {
        'error': 'not-found'
    };
    return {
        userInfo,
        extraUserInfo,
        avatarImage
    };
}
};
getUser(args[0]).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.extraUserInfo.error === 'not-found' ? result.userInfo.name : result.extraUserInfo.user.name);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```